# Charter internet weird experience with intermittent signal

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

We've had Charter communications for about 6 years. The last 2 we've used a D-link dir-655 router with their modem and my wireless router served access to a 23 room house without issue for those 2 years. I live in Western Mass. We had tornadoes here beginning of November. Power/cable were down for 7 days.

After all was back to running, we had wireless access that wasn't as quick but it was working for a couple of weeks.  Suddenly it stopped working. I couldn't get a wireless signal any more. The laptop next to the modem couldn't connect because the network card hadn't worked in a long time. The desktop downstairs is 6 months old and was connected wirelessly. I even ran a network cable all the way downstairs to my desktop and that didn't work in any of the 4 ports out of the router, either.  I even have a network cable tester that showed the cable was good.  We decided to ask the cable company to replace the modem with a modem/router so we wouldn't have to buy a new one.  The tech came, installed a Netgear and everything was fine for about 4 hours.  Then the wireless connectivity issues started again. Every computer, wireless printer, magicJack, web-tv, Apple TV and cell phone (12 devices) had intermittent connectivity issues.  Rebooting the Netgear would give us about 2 hours of uninterrupted bliss and them it would start again. The speedtest.net was running download speeds between 2 and 10.  Charter sent another tech who said the Netgear device was not a good model and replaced it with a Netgear Docsis 3.0.  This brought my signal through his diagnostic programs back up to where they should be, he told me.  Even while he was there, I showed him that the speedtest.net was still bringing me inconsistent and slow speeds.  He finally put in a powered signal booster splitter on my inside line.  We reboot everything and all was good for about 5 hours again.  After that, we had the same issues.  This time, however, even rebooting everything would only last a few minutes of uninterrupted signal.  Also hardwiring the computer downstairs would only give me moments of connectivity and then I'd have to seesaw back and forth through the device manager with the wireless by switching off and on the Ethernet and the wireless cards and this would only work once in a while.

By the way, each time a technician was here, they said they checked the outside lines and said they showed only strong signals coming into the house and that the last modem/router was showing history of good signals.

Can anyone think of something that might be the cause of this issue?  I mentioned the tornado because it's after that when the signal didn't work exactly the same and then stopped working entirely after a while.  I spend many hours on the internet per day and am in charge of several websites.  I'm about to jump off a roof.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having an electrician take a look at the wiring and the outlet the router/network hardware is plugged into. it's possible that the issues you are experiencing are due to bad/faulty power causing the devices to malfunction.